# How to reconfigure postfix with puppet?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, postfix-mta, dpkg

I'm using a bunch of ubuntu virtual machines (VMs), which are using the same mail relay server. The VMs are managed by puppet. I've created a simple module to install and configure postfix as "satellite system" on all VMs. See the module's manifest file below. The module is called from node blocks as follows:

```
node "mynode.com" {
  class { 'postfix_satellite': mailname => 'mydomain.com', relayhost => 'myrelay.com' }
}
```

The problem is that this solution installs and configures postfix at the first run, but it does not re-configure postfix if the template for the preseed file is changed. Only the preseed file is installed and I have to run `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive postfix` manually. Any idea is welcome.

```
# Puppet module: postfix_satellite
#

class postfix_satellite ( $mailname, $relayhost ) {

  case $operatingsystem {
    ubuntu:  { }
    default: { fail("postfix_satellite: unsupported OS: ${operatingsystem}") }
  }

  $preseed_dir      = '/var/local/preseed'
  $preseed_file = "postfix.preseed"

  # -- Packages

  package { 'postfix':
    ensure          => present,
    responsefile    => "${preseed_dir}/${preseed_file}",
    require                 => File["${preseed_dir}/${preseed_file}"],
  }

  package { 'mailutils':
    ensure  => present,
    require => Package['postfix'],
  }

  # -- Service      

  service { 'postfix':
    ensure          => running,
    enable          => true,
    hasstatus       => true,
    hasrestart      => true,
    require => Package['postfix'],
  }

  file { $preseed_dir:
    ensure          => directory,
    owner           => root,
    group           => root,
    mode            => 755,
  }

  file { "${preseed_dir}/${preseed_file}":
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 644,
    content => template("postfix_satellite/${preseed_file}.erb"),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on managing postfix through the package preseed file, you can use the sledge hammer approach.

```
exec { 'apt-get install --reinstall postfix':
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe   => File["${preseed_dir}/${preseed_file}"],
    path        => '/bin:/usr/bin'
}
```

If I were in your shoes, though, I would look for an [existing module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/thias/postfix) to actively manage postfix even after installation.